# Kafka Streams - Best way to do lookups in remote store via interactive queries?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a bit of confusion and I would like some clarification. I have something I'm working on. I want to have one Kafka Streams topology that will have five separate KStreams reading from their own respective topic and dumping that data into a large monolithic topic. Next I'll have a GlobalKTable that will read from that monolithic topic and materialize a global store let's say called `lookupStore`. I want to have this materialized global store as basically a "lookup" table for other Kafka Streams applications. I've done some reading on exposing this with an RPC layer with the `application.server` configuration which will be in the form of some unique `host:port`.

Now I want to have however many separate microservices each that are Kafka Streams applications that will perform are processing events from a KStream and then doing a lookup on `lookupStore` via an interactive query. For instance a `.filter()` operation based on whether the lookup on that `lookupStore` returned a value or not. So here's my confusion... let's assume I hardcode that exposed RPC layer on `host:port` how do I query `lookupStore` specifically to query it. If this was in the same topology/local instance you could just do something like `lookupStore.get("key")`... but how do you do this within a remote Kafka Streams instance?

Or does connecting to that RPC layer expose that state store to the remote application so that it "knows" of it and you can query the `lookupStore` like as if it was a local instance? Is this feasible or am I going down the wrong path?

Comment: Typically, you will use the KafkaStreams API to discover and query remote Kafka Streams instance using your own RPC layer (e.g REST, GRPC). Maybe this project can save you some time as it offers a built-in support to query your State Stores :  https://www.azkarrastreams.io/

Answer (score 0):

If your microservices (which are streams applications) share the same Kafka cluster as the main streaming app (that generates GlobalKTable), then they can access the Table topic corresponding to the same application and do KTable join or lookupStore.get("key"). Also it is not recommended to do remote API calls within a stream application to do lookups, because of latency. If the two Kafak clusters are different, then you could explore replicating the topics (GlobalKTable and State Store change log topics) using something like mirror maker.